# How to extract the emails from the JSON in the PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

How can I get the emails from this array?

```
array(16) { 
    [0]=> string(273) ""guid":"","contactId":"44","contactName":"_, atri","email":"atri_megrez@yahoo.com","emaillink":"http:\/\/mrd.mail.yahoo.com\/compose?To=atri_megrez%40yahoo.com","isConnection":false,"connection":"","displayImg":null,"msgrID":"atri_megrez","msgrStatus":"","isMsgrBuddy":122}," 
    [1]=> string(260) ""guid":"","contactId":"100","contactName":"afrin","email":"fida_cuty123@yahoo.com","emaillink":"http:\/\/mrd.mail.yahoo.com\/compose?To=fida_cuty123%40yahoo.com","isConnection":false,"connection":"","displayImg":null,"msgrID":"","msgrStatus":"","isMsgrBuddy":false}," 
    [2]=> string(258) ""guid":"","contactId":"101","contactName":"afrin","email":"waliyani@yahoo.com","emaillink":"http:\/\/mrd.mail.yahoo.com\/compose?To=waliyani%40yahoo.com","isConnection":false,"connection":"","displayImg":null,"msgrID":"","msgrStatus":"","isMsgrBuddy":false},"
}
```

Comment: Will you please make your array a little bit readable? May be copy the output out of `"<pre>".print_r(arr)."</pre>"` and paste it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like each of the strings in that array is [JSON](http://www.json.org/) data.

If you're using a modern version of PHP, you can use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) to get to the data into a usable format.

```
foreach($array as $string) {
    $json = json_decode($string);
    echo "Email = {$json->email}\n";
}
```

Comment: The opening `{` bracket is missing from the strings, the closing one is there. Add it in your json_decode call.

Answer (score 1):

If you could post an example of the data (eg: where it comes from, a properly formatted example of the `print_r()` output of the array) that would help, however from what I can gather this will get the emails from the array:

```
/* Make $array hold the given array */

$emails = array();
foreach($array as $contact){
    $emails[] = $contact['email'];
}

// All emails
print_r($emails);
```

Comment: @Charles's answer is the way to go, now that I can see you're using JSON data

Answer (score 1):

you can run a regexp on every array element. something like this: /"email":"(.+?)"/

```
$emails = array();
foreach ($array as $str)
{
    if (preg_match('/"email":"(.+?)"/', $str, $matches))
    {
        $emails[] = $matches[1];
    }
}
```